# Nuxt Auth - User Data not set

Tags: authentication, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I try to do a login via nuxt-auth module. As a response I get the token and then the user data is delivered. However, `this.$Auth.loggedIn` is `false` and `this.$Auth.user` is `undefined`. I have been fighting for 3 days and can not get any further. Hope somebody can help me.

**login**

```
await this.$auth.login({
    data: {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }
}).then(() => {
    this.$router.push('/dashboard')
}).catch(err => {
    this.snackbar.show = true;
})
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
        local: {
            endpoints: {
                login: {
                    url: '/auth/login',
                    method: 'post',
                    propertyName: 'access_token'
                },
                logout: {
                    url: '/auth/logout',
                    method: 'post'
                },
                user: {
                    url: '/auth/me',
                    method: 'post'
                },
                tokenRequired: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**response login**

```
{
"access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYXBpLmFwcHJlexxxxxxxcxXRoXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTUzODI5NTczMywiZXhwIjoxNTM4Mjk5MzMzLCJuYmYiOjE1MzgyOTU3MzMsImp0aSI6ImdtWWVyZTViQjk1cU5BRG8iLCJzdWIiOjIsInBydiI6IjYwODM2NzQ0MzQ4ZDQzMTk4NzE4N2ZjMWM2YzIzMjYxMDcyMWE5ZjAifQ.JhOiwIg7StzZR71aqYyI9rJpPXVclmddzPSIwqCIUN4",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 3600
}
```

**response user**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Dominik Dummy",
    "email": "dummy@andreas-pabst.de",
    "created_at": {
        "date": "2018-09-28 09:11:31.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "date": "2018-09-28 09:11:31.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "self": "https:\/\/api.apprex.de\/api\/users\/2"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are u sure you need post request for getting user? If so - check the network if the user get request done.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok after a long try, I finally solved it. The problem was that `auth.fetchUser()` requires a property `user` in the user response, which is not present in my user response. I set the propertyName to false in the nuxt.config.js and now it works

***nuxt.config.js**

```
auth: {
strategies: {
    local: {
        endpoints: {
            login: {
                url: '/auth/login',
                method: 'post',
                propertyName: 'access_token'
            },
            logout: {
                url: '/auth/logout',
                method: 'post'
            },
            user: {
                url: '/auth/me',
                method: 'post',
                propertyName: false // <--- Default "user"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Currently I am not sure if this is a fault in the module

Comment: Note that some tutorials I've seen say to set `propertyName` to `undefined` — that doesn't work. Your answer is the only one that's worked for me!

Comment: you save my time

Answer (score 21):

**Update for auth-next": "^5.0.0"**

You will have to set `property: false` instead of `propertyName`.
So your nuxt.config.js might be as follows:

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer'
        },
        user: {
          property: false, // <--- Default "user"
          autoFetch: true
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'api/login', method: 'post' },
          logout: { url: 'api/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: 'api/user', method: 'get' }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an updated answer 

Comment: I wanted to avoid making an extra request to the `user` endpoint. To do this, I also needed to set `endpoints.user` to `false`. 

As the documentation says: "...unless you disable the user endpoint with endpoints.user: false you will still need to implement the user endpoint so that auth can fetch the user information on e.g. page refresh." 
(https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local/#user)

Answer (score 4):

You should call the `this.$auth.fetchUser()` for fills `user` data and `loggedIn` in the `auth` store  [Docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#fetchuser)

Comment: No, its called automatically after login https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/blob/dev/lib/schemes/local.js#L54

Comment: Yes I know it, but I think you wanted to call it manually and if you have the response from `self` API so it would be great and you can reload the page after getting the response for debugging it if user object fills after reload make sure you `this.$auth.fetchUser()` does work, else trouble due to not call `fetchUser` function

Comment: thanks for this function! This  needs to be called if we are updating user's data on backend