# Problem implementing nuxtjs/auth using local strategy

Tags: api, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm following a nuxtjs tutorial and I'm having issues implementing nuxtjs/auth loginWith. It is pretty straightforward but I don't know why it doesn't work for me. tested with postman and the API responds with a token;[image: api response on postman1]

[image: postman response 2]

Everything looks okay, saves the token to cookies and local storage. Signup also works but it doesn't login. When I inspect with Vue dev tools, it shows login false and the user undefined when I'm expecting a user object. What could be wrong?
[image: vue dev tools]

As it is, here's the method for Login.vue

```
async onLogin() {
  try {
      this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
        data: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }
      });
      this.$router.push("/");
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

here's also my nuxt.config.js

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:3000'
export default {



    /*
    ** Nuxt rendering mode
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
    */
    mode: 'universal',
    /*
    ** Nuxt target
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
    */
    target: 'server',
    /*
    ** Headers of the page
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
    */
    head: {
        title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
        ],
        link: [
            { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
            { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/font-awesome/css/all.css' },
            { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/default.css' }
        ]
    },
    /*
    ** Global CSS
    */
    css: [],
    /*
    ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
    ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
    */
    plugins: [],
    /*
    ** Auto import components
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
    */
    components: true,
    /*
    ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
    */
    buildModules: [],
    /*
    ** Nuxt.js modules
    */
    modules: [
        // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        '@nuxtjs/auth',
        // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt/content
        // '@nuxt/content',
    ],
    /*
    **Axios Module config
    ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
    */
    axios: {
        proxy: true,
        baseURL: URL
    },
    proxy: {
        "/api": URL
    },
    /*
    ** Build configuration
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
    */
    build: {
        extend(config, ctx) {}
    },

    auth: {
        strategies: {
            local: {
                endpoints: {
                    login: {
                        url: "/api/auth/login",
                        method: "post",
                        propertyName: "token"
                    },
                    user: {
                        url: "/api/auth/user",
                        method: "get",
                        propertyName: "token"
                    },
                    logout: true
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576160/nuxt-auth-user-data-not-set

Comment: your endpoint url within the nuxt application is wrong

Comment: could you please point out the error? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
auth: {
        strategies: {
            local: {
                endpoints: {
                    login: {
                        url: "/api/auth/login",
                        method: "post",
                        propertyName: "data.token"
                    },
                    user: {
                        url: "/api/auth/user",
                        method: "get",
                        propertyName: "data.user"
                    },
                    logout: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As the response from the api is received inside data, when axios is used.

Comment: Can you please look "network" tab of the developer's tool, to figure out if the desired APIs are being hit. If yes, then look into the response as well.

Comment: This solution returns data but not the expected data. returns error with my verify-token.js I'm finding it hard to understand why. The APIs return the expected data via postman

Comment: View the code that is being used by postman by clicking the button "View Code", and compare the same with that of yours, see what difference you find.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Somehow, it only updates the after I refresh the entire browser. I thought the Hot reloading would suffice but it works. this is my auth strategies setup

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
        local: {
            endpoints: {
                login: {
                    url: "/api/auth/login",
                    method: "post",
                    propertyName: "data.token"
                },
                user: {
                    url: "/api/auth/user",
                    method: "get",
                    propertyName: "data.user"
                },
                logout: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to all that commented. It has helped my confidence and problem solving ability.